# Image does not update when appending newly inserted row using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to insert data using ajax and show that newly inserted data in a div, but the record (i.e. image and name ) does not get updated it.

I don't want to reload page, the newly entered record should be shown without page reload, but it shows only the initial name and image.

I can't understand whats the problem. Please help. Following is the code i am using static data which is stored in a variable as an example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'add.php',
    data: data,
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        d = new Date();
        var img_name='amit.png'+'?'+d.getTime();

        var s_name='Ashish';
        $('#main').prepend('<img alt="client" id="p_img"><h1>'+s_name+'</h1>');
        $('#p_img').attr("src", "image/Amit.png");
    },
    error: function (error) 
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: what's your newly inserted image filename? Is it always 'amit.png' ?

Comment: no it is different every time data is inserted

Comment: but i get the same i.e. initial one every time success part is executed. If i change var s_name=''Amit" then also it will show Ashish

Comment: shouldnt you get that name as a variable? why its hardcoded there?

Comment: You're hard coding the values,

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, is that your issue?!

Comment: I have hardcoded it so that i can check it by changing variable everytime that success part is executed but the same issue is there.

Comment: can you clarify your question? if you hardcoded the image, suirely you will get the same image always.

Comment: But are you using duplicate IDs? If ya, then `$('#p_img')` you are only targeting first matched element

Comment: Have u seen any error in console ? show the html of `'#main'`.

Comment: There is no error in console and second time i changed var img_name='Pankaj.png'+'?'+d.getTime(); but i get the initial image amit.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the src attribute use the response/variable/generated file name?

Like this:

```
$('#p_img').attr("src", '/image/' + img_name);
```

Instead of this:

```
$('#p_img').attr("src", "image/Amit.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be two reasons :

- the image you are prepending to the DOM is not yet in the DOM when you are trying to add the src
- or the src is not existing (should be an absolute or relative path)

Try to prepend the image with the src

```
$('#main').prepend('<img alt="client" src="ABSOLUTE_OR_RELATIVE_PATH/image/Amit.png"><h1>Amit</h1>');
```

Also there is no need to create a variable s_name which you only use once.

Comment: prepend() is sync so cannot be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can done it easily by returing List of data and populating the div with ajax success result.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'add.php',
        data: data,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        // in data you are getting your result ...
        // now for ease split json format data and store in list 
        // m not sure about your formate so m assuming at first index it                          
        //should be image URL so..
        var res = data.split(","); 
        var imgSrc = res[0];
        $('#main').prepend('<img alt="client" id="p_img"/>');
         $('#p_img').attr("src", imgSrc);
        },
        error: function (error) 
        {

        }
    });
```